# move obstacles randomly in game scene in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am creating a game in Xcode using cocos2d-x(c++) game engine , and I am a beginner to this,
In this game in the game scene i tried to move obstacles randomly, but it is moving in sequential order,anyone please give me the solution. Following is the code I used to move the obstacle

```
obs1 = CCSprite::create("branch.png");
int val=arc4random%7;
obs1->setPosition(ccp(winwsize/val,winhsize/8));
this->addChild(obs1 ,-1);
obs1->setVisible(true);

schedule(schedule_selector(SceneThree::OnUpdateFrame));


void GameScene::OnUpdateFrame3(float deltaTime3)
{ 
if (obs1->getPosition().x < -(winwsize/2))
{
    obs1->setPosition(ccp(obs1->getPosition().x+(2*winwsize),obs1->getPosition().y));
}
 obs1->setPosition(ccp(obs1->getPosition().x-17,obs1->getPosition().y));

}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Where is the ~random~ part of the code? Looks like you're only subtracting 17 from the x-position

Comment: just now i added the random part please refer it.

Comment: but now you've added it to the initial position, and not to the update-position part =p

Comment: Also, AFAIK `arc4random` is not supported on Android out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you are using a random value only for the the initial position.
And on every tick (that is the update function), you are just subtracting 17 from the x position, which should result in a sequential move.

Also, the way your random number is generated, will give a value 0-6. Hence you will get values like "winWsize / (a number from 0-6)" which might result in a division by zero Or if not the values would be limited IMO (compared the entire screen)

Why not make it something like arc4random() % winWSize (this will give u a value 0-winWSize)?

Also, make sure you use this (arc4random() % winWSize) in your "OnUpdateFrame3" function so that on every tick u get a new random position, try

```
void GameScene::OnUpdateFrame3(float deltaTime3)
{ 

 float xValue = arc4random() % winWSize;
 obs1->setPosition(ccp(xValue,obs1->getPosition().y));

}
```

But this is only moving it along the X Axis, u can use a similar technique for Y axis as well. Also, arc4random may not work on Android hence you should also check this,

http://blog.kibotu.net/android/c-arc4random-on-android-windows-and-linux

Or, you can also use "timestamp" to generate a random value on your own. Choice it yours.